# Js:Como hago para mostrar por pantalla los dias de la semana con un array de forma ordenada y que ademas me los pida?¿

Tags: javascript

URGENTE* Hice esto y nose como ordenar la array ni como hacer para que a parte de que salgan los dias por pantalla me los pida como dice el enunciado.Alguien que pueda echarme un cable?¿
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este tipo de respuestas en las cuales las personas esperan que simplemente resuelvan su tarea, sin realizar ninguna investigacion previa ni poner ejemplo del código relevante, presentando como problema el enunciado de la tarea/examen y en este caso, si quiera seguir las reglas del sitio utilizando el formato correcto del código (no una imagen); son dañinas para el sitio y la gente que en serio quiere apernder y resolver problemas reales... Por esto mismo este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas. Te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Lecturas recomendadas: [Te podrían votar negativamente por pedir ayuda urgente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152) y [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el enunciado?